# How to completely clear/set text of WinRT's RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

How does one completely overwrite or clear the text (and formatting) of WinRT's RichEditBox?

I'm asking because the method [SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.settext) of it's Document property seems only to append new text.

Thus the "binding" as below:

```
void Vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Content")
        richEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, Vm.Content);
}

private void ContentChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RichEditBox box = (RichEditBox)sender;

    string content;
    box.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out content);

    Vm.Content = content;
}
```

where `Vm_PropertyChanged` just listens for changes in the `Content` string property of the ViewModel and `ContentChanged` is a handler for `TextChanged` event of the RichEditBox, will create an infinite loop constantly appending "\r" to the Vm.Content and the box's text itself.
When you replace `TextGetOptions.None` with `TextGetOptions.FormatRtf` the ViewModel's `Content` property gets even more messy adding something that looks like empty RTF paragraphs.

Here's the Content property definition in the ViewModel so you can ensure that everything's ok with it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Content" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ContentPropertyName = "Content";

    private string _content;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Content property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return _content;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_content == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(ContentPropertyName);
            _content = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ContentPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Some experiments:

```
        richEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, string.Empty);
        string content;
        richEditBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out content);
        //content became "\r"

        richEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, content);
        richEditBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out content);
        //content became "\r\r"
```

EDIT:

Another experiment:

A simple workaround for `TextGetOptions.None` is trimming that extra "\r" on output.
However with `TextGetOptions.FormatRtf` things aren't just that simple:

```
        RichEditBox box = new RichEditBox();

        box.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, string.Empty);
        string content;
        box.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out content);

        //content is now
        // {\\rtf1\\fbidis\\ansi\\ansicpg1250\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang1045{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil Segoe UI;}}\r\n{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}\r\n{\\*\\generator Riched20 6.2.9200}\\viewkind4\\uc1 \r\n\\pard\\ltrpar\\tx720\\cf1\\f0\\fs17\\lang1033\\par\r\n}\r\n\0

        box.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, content);
        box.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out content);

        //and now it's
        // {\\rtf1\\fbidis\\ansi\\ansicpg1250\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang1045{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil Segoe UI;}{\\f1\\fnil Segoe UI;}}\r\n{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}\r\n{\\*\\generator Riched20 6.2.9200}\\viewkind4\\uc1 \r\n\\pard\\ltrpar\\tx720\\cf1\\f0\\fs17\\lang1033\\par\r\n\r\n\\pard\\ltrpar\\tx720\\f1\\fs17\\par\r\n}\r\n\0
```

I apologize for my English. All corrections concerning it are also welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra /r (or \par if you query for RTF) appears to be a bug in the RichEditBox. It can be worked around however, by doing something like this:

```
        string temp;
        // Do not ask for RTF here, we just want the raw text
        richEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out temp);
        var range = richEditBox.Document.GetRange(0, temp.Length - 1);

        string content;
        // Ask for RTF here, if desired.
        range.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, null)`.  From the documentation of [SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.settext):

> If the string is NULL, the text in the document is deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately, AgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Which is strange if the documentation says so.

Comment: And since the documentation concerns only the ITextDocument interface we never know what the implementing class will do.

Comment: @MichaelK.Sondej Does using `SetText(..., string.Empty)` work?

Comment: Well, if I do only `richEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, string.Empty);` in the `Vm_PropertyChanged` it clears the box in a loop, so everything typed is cleared. That is expect, but when I do

`richEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, string.Empty);

string content;

richEditBox.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out content);`

the content is "\r".
So if I clear the box and try to set text to something different it still creates an infinite loop because every consecutive GetText call adds "\r" to the actual content.

Comment: And because GetText adds that character to the content every time, Vm.Content property never detects the `Content == value` situation thus creating the loop.

Check out the edited question for example.